# How do I save a Web Page?

Tags: windows, pdf, printer

I have tried many programs and solutions to save web pages (html, mht, doc, pdf). My favorite software was an addon for browsers from Omnipage (OCR). What I like about this is that it prints the whole page (continuously) and it doesn't write the URL or page numbers on the page, which I find annoying.

Does anyone know a software like this one (freeware or not)?

I  tried CutePDF and it didn't work for me.

I want this for my offline use and would prefer a PDF.

Comment: What is the canonical question? Or is this the one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want this simply to keep offline, there are a variety of options.

[Chrome Scrapbook](https://chrome.google.com/extensions/detail/gokffdfnlmampchciemmflgbckijpmlb) is a perfectly valid option for offline usage, although it doesn't do PDFs.

**If you need PDFs, you can use either the [PDFDownload](http://www.pdfdownload.org/pdf_bookmarklet.html) or [Joliprint](http://joliprint.com/).** Personally, I prefer Joliprint because it reformats the page to make it more readable, though you probably will want to try both yourself.

PDF can be saved as PDFs, so there's no problem there...

And Word documents can be saved as PDF using Microsoft's [Save as PDF](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&FamilyID=4d951911-3e7e-4ae6-b059-a2e79ed87041) addon.

Comment: i know about the addon :)

Comment: @Remus What about Joliprint?

Comment: just tested joliprint, it's very useful because you don't have to install any software and it's very simple...

Answer (score 0):

What is the purpose ?

I use the following extension for saving pages:

Chrome Scrapbook

https://chrome.google.com/extensions/detail/gokffdfnlmampchciemmflgbckijpmlb

There is a similar one for firefox.

Comment: The link is broken (404).

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean to save the individual files (.html, .css, .js, et al.) or do you mean to save a readable version for offline reading? Or do you mean printing? What web browser are you using?

If you are trying to read web pages offline in IE, choose File → Save As → Web Archive (.mht). I'm guessing that's what you meant because you mention .mht in your question. This allows offline reading of static pages, but  does not update dynamic Flash or HTML5 pages.

You do not need to convert pages to PDF using CutePDF or anything else unless you want to read the pages on a non-Microsoft OS. If that's what you mean, please say so.

If you are trying to print the web page, just choose Print in IE. If you want to remove the file path and page number, choose File → Page Setup and remove the Header and Footer commands.

Comment: i want to keep an offline version (PDF preferable)

Comment: Every alternative I described will keep an offline version. If this is not adequate, please explain why. Why does CutePDF not work for you? The URL and page numbers? I explained how to remove them, what happens when you do that?

Answer (score 0):

You can try [Teleport Pro](http://www.tenmax.com/teleport/pro/features.htm) to download & surf web sites offline.

It has too many features to customize.

Comment: I've been using Offline Explorer and HTTrack (www.httrack.com) but i want something else

Answer (score 0):

You could use the Wget in linux, there are arguments that can crawl a page and save a local copy, with all the hyperlinks changed to their local counterparts.

Such as

wget -r 20 -k sitename.com

Comment: i was looking for a windows solution

Comment: @Remus Rigo: Wget works on Windows too (I once used it for ***serial*** downloading of videos and podcast episodes from a .bat script). There is a binary around and it likely also works [Cygwin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cygwin), [Git Bash](https://superuser.com/questions/1053633/what-is-git-bash-for-windows-anyway), etc.