# Notepad++ opens up via git bash, but receiving error

Tags: notepad++, environment-variables, git-bash

git Bash recognises Notepad++ command and opens Notepad++. But i receive the following error.(kkris is my username)

> `error: C:\Users\kkris\AppData\Roaming\Notepad++\plugins\Config\Hunspell\en_US.us
>   r: cannot open`

Comment: Bash would be Linux, Notepad++ is a Windows program. It's unclear what you're trying to achieve or what your setup looks like. If you're using WSL you need to include that information. Your error message is incomplete. Path variables for Linux and Windows are very different.

Comment: @Seth, git for Windows does come with a Bash shell, so it's quite possible to have "git Bash" on Windows. see [here](https://superuser.com/a/1053657/422309) for more.

Comment: @Krishna-Swaroop-K, does Notepad++ load okay when run from a Windows shortcut rather than from git Bash?  
Could you edit the post and add **? > Debug Info > Copy debug info into clipboard** into your question, along with a screenshot of **Plugins > DSpellCheck > About** (DSpellCheck is the plugin that uses the Hunspell config directory)