# Recovering deleted files deleted with Git Bash on Windows using rm -rf

Tags: bash, git, restore, rm

While working in Git Bash on my Windows laptop, I accidently deleted important files and folders using rm -rf on C:>. Is there a way to restore them? Since the OS is Windows while tool is bash, could not identify any recycle bean sort of place. Appreciate your help

Answer (score 1):

No matter what OS, `rm -rf` command deletes files permanently, without an intermediate Recycle Bin stage. There's no going back.

If you are using Windows OS, you can try to use file recovery softwares, but there is no guarantee that they will work.

- https://www.bleepingcomputer.com/download/recuva/
- https://www.bleepingcomputer.com/download/minitool-power-data-recovery-free/

Next time please use `rm -i` command, which will ask you *do you really want to remove these files*?

There have been many stories of people on the internet who weren't careful with the powerful commands, and completely screwed their computer or their data as a result, sometimes losing thousands of dollars. It's like working with a knife. It is better to learn about careless experience of others than to have such experience ourselves.

- https://www.reddit.com/r/linux/comments/1zjcqs/what_stupid_mistakes_have_you_made_while_using/
- https://www.reddit.com/r/linux/comments/k57n1/what_was_your_worst_oh_fuck_moment_with_linux/
- https://dev.to/ben/tell-me-about-a-time-you-messed-up-47an

Comment: @Ramhound Git bash isn't WSL. It is a Windows terminal with Linux commands such as `rm` implemented as Windows executables, in other words recompiled to use the Windows system API for achieving the same functionality. It is the same result as if you ran Windows `rd` command. https://superuser.com/a/1053657